# Count occurences of just keys from dictionary in a string

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

EDIT/UPDATE: I see my problem - I didn't use 'lowercase' option, so when in file word had uppercase, then it didn't work! For example, I should've used "GHI" not "ghi" in some cases

I have a program which opens log file on FTP server and reads it every 1 sec. If new logs appear, then it is inserted into tkinter Text widget. Here's also colors.txt text file, which looks something like that:

```
abc=green
def=yellow
ghi=blue
```

Function:

```
def readdata(text,dir,logfile,title,stop_event):
    scroll.config(command=t.yview)
    global sftp
    cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
    cnopts.hostkeys = None
    sftp = pysftp.Connection('ip', username='user', password='pass', cnopts=cnopts)
    root.title(title)
    t.insert(tk.END, text+"LOADING\n\n")
    sftp.chdir('logs')
    sftp.chdir(dir)
    active_log = logfile
    with sftp.open(active_log, mode="r") as file:
        old_logs = file.read().decode('ASCII')
        t.insert(tk.END, old_logs)
        t.see(tk.END)
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        with sftp.open(active_log, mode="r") as file:
            new_logs = file.read().decode('ASCII')
        if new_logs != old_logs:
            t.insert(tk.END, new_logs[len(old_logs):])
            state = var1.get()
            if state==1:
                t.see(tk.END)
            old_logs = new_logs
            with open('colors.txt', 'r') as f:
                for line in f.readlines():
                    phrases, colors= line.rstrip("\n").split("=")
                    myObject[phrases] = colors  # myObject = {'abc': 'green', 'def': 'yellow', 'ghi': 'blue'}
            my_list = list(myObject.keys())
            for k in my_list:       # my_list = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
                print(new_logs.count(k))
        time.sleep(1)
```

In function above, code is taking just each key and puts it into list, so:
my_list = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']

I want to check, how many times each of these words appear in logs (which has 'new_logs'/'old_logs' variables). However, I'm not successfull with it, because most of my trials ended up in counting just one of words, so it looked like this:

```
abc=1245
def=0
ghi=0
```

I also tried Counter() from Collections, but it was counting occurence of each letter (??) which even wasn't occuring in any of word from list?
Why it doesn't count occurences of EACH key, but just one? Here should not be any zeros, cuz in logs these keys were appearing many times.

Sample log from this FTP server:

```
2024-03-18 12:06:48 >>> +CPSI: LTE,Online,260-03,0xE2F0,71697430,43,EUTRAN-BAND1,50,3,0,33,59,51,21  OK  
2024-03-18 12:07:10 main RUN_PDP_WATCHDOG
2024-03-18 12:07:10 <<< AT+CGACT?

2024-03-18 12:07:10 >>> +CGACT: 1,1  OK  
2024-03-18 12:07:10 <<< AT+NETOPEN?

2024-03-18 12:07:10 >>> +NETOPEN: 1  OK  
2024-03-18 12:07:16 main RUN_NETWORK_MONITORING
2024-03-18 12:07:16 <<< AT+CSQ

2024-03-18 12:07:16 >>> +CSQ: 26,99  OK  
2024-03-18 12:07:16 <<< AT+CNSMOD?

2024-03-18 12:07:16 >>> +CNSMOD: 0,8  OK  
2024-03-18 12:07:16 <<< AT+CREG?

2024-03-18 12:07:16 >>> +CREG: 0,1  OK  
2024-03-18 12:07:16 <<< AT+CPSI?

2024-03-18 12:07:16 >>> +CPSI: LTE,Online,260-03,0xE2F0,71697430,43,EUTRAN-BAND1,50,3,0,29,60,53,20  OK
```

Comment: You should simplify question and focus on the problem. Whats your problem or what fail?

Comment: I'm unable (with my knowledge) to implement working for-loop which will count occurence of EVERY word (or just key from key:value pairs) from list/dictionary in big-string (logs text). For now, it only counts occurences of one key, and for rest keys it assigns 0 (zero). For example, it should give: abc=100,def=121,ghi=322. But it just gives this: abc=100,def=0,ghi=0. Also, as new logs are appearing, it should count "new occurences".

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a text-file to do python well-known work actually.
I'd recommend to change colors.txt to a python-file or yaml-file instead.

Besides, you are using rsplit(), which only removes spaces at the end of a line

```
with open('colors.txt', 'r') as f:
for line in f.readlines():
    phrases, colors = line.strip().split("=")  # Remove Spaces and split at =
    myObject[phrases.strip()] = colors # your actuall seeking phrases as keys and colors as values
```

phrases.strip() makes sure your very special way of storing information in a text-file matches a key-value construct

Comment: But the output was same with my code & your code? I mean, myObject looks still same, and it gives zeros again, too

Comment: the solution will not lay in your python-code I guess, change your key-values using a yaml-file or python-file

Comment: I changed colors.txt to colors.yaml and colors.yml - didn't work. Same with colors.py, it is correctly counting occurence of this first key (for example when new log with 'abc' appears in adds +1) but for rest zero is zero and it didnt change

Comment: `
phrases_colors = {
    'abc': 'green',
    'def': 'yellow',
    'ghi': 'blue'
}

...

            for phrase in phrases_colors:
                print(new_logs.count(phrase))

`

if this is still not logging correctly, we will need a sample of the log

Comment: -added fragment of log from log file. These logs are mostly repeating. I want for example count occurences of 'AT+CPSI'

Comment: edit: I see my problem - I didn't use 'lowercase' option, so when in file word had uppercase, then it didn't work! For example, I should've used "GHI" not "ghi" in some cases